# Check keyboard KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER click from editText

Tags: java, android

I have an editText and I want to take the user to another Activity when the enter action of the keyboard is pressed. I tried adding this to the editText's xml:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSend"
```

And this is my code:

```
            final EditText searchField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchRecipe);
            searchField.setImeActionLabel("Cerca", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

            searchField.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {

                    Intent goDetails = new Intent(RecipesList.this, RecipeDetails.class);
                    goDetails.putExtra("Keyword",searchField.getText());
                    startActivity(goDetails);

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The enter button has its name changed but the action isn't fired. Can you help me understand where's the problem with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
final EditText searchField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchRecipe);
     searchField.setImeActionLabel("Cerca", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
     searchField.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                    // do stuff here
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Edited

KeyEvents can also be listened this way.

```
 searchField.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    // do stuff here
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: I had to pay more attention on what I was writing, ty the first solution worked :)! will accept as soon as I can